# Why is prepareWithInvocationTarget: specific to NSUndoManager?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsinvocation

Compare...

```
NSInvocation* invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[performer methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(playFile:)]];
[invocation setSelector:@selector(playFile:)];
[invocation setTarget:performer];
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithString:@"reverse.wav"];
[invocation setArgument:&string atIndex:2];
```

...with...

```
NSInvocation* invocation = [[NSInvocation prepareWithTarget:performer] playFile:@"reverse.wav"];
```

. Why isn't such a method implemented?

Comment: You can make your code cleaner by using a variable for the selector `SEL sel = @selector(playFile:)`, which also avoids mistyping long selector names, and by just setting `NSString* string = @"reverse.wav"` - the `-stringWithString:` call is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just isn't, but there is no shortage of third-party implementations of the same functionality, such as the one written up at and created for [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/construct-nsinvocation-for-any-message.html).

Comment: So strange that it isn't there; I thought there'd be a reason. Great link!

Comment: @andyvn22: People just don't create NSInvocations all that much, so a nicer way to do it probably isn't very high on Apple's to-do list.

Comment: Besides, we have blocks now. Finally :)